# Javascript window.close() and window.stop() Logical or Technical?

Tags: javascript, html

Maybe my question is very simple but i am new at HTML and JavaScript.

I want to learn **window.close()** and **window.stop()** ,

So I tried it in a simple HTML page. But there is a problem, I am using my function in **a** tag. and **window.stop()** does not stop the operation. I want to stop the redirection if confirm dialog not true. How can I fix this problem?

HTML FILE:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title> My page </title>    
    <script src="my_javascript_file.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>

    <a href = "http://www.google.com" onclick="whereAreYouGoing()">Go</a>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**my_javascript_file.js:**

```JS
function whereAreYouGoing(){
    
    var exit = confirm("Are You Want to Sure to Leave?");
    
    if(exit){
        window.close();
    }
    
    else
        window.stop();

}
```

Comment: You can only close a window that was opened with the open function [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.close)

Comment: no! i dont think like you. If i use <input type="button" onclick="window.close()" /> this closes the window. So close() can close a page.

Comment: @hakiko - In most browsers that will only close windows that were opened via JavaScript code. _"So close() can close a page."_ - There's a big difference between closing the window and navigating to a different page. I'm not even sure what you mean by "close a page"?

Comment: you are right @nnnnnn window.close() is unnecessary for this example. If user click to OK buton <a> tag chance the page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting

```
 
  window.onbeforeunload = whereAreYouGoing;
```

at the beginning of the javascript code. 
onbeforeunload always runs before a window is closed; so, if you wire the function to it, it'll call the function before closing the window. 
Although that will display the dialog to the user before closing the window, all browsers gives the user the opportunity to override the function; this means that if the user wants to close the window, the browser will close the window, even if your function tries to prevent that from happening. 
 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

That's not what [`window.stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.stop) is for.

Since you're using an inline `onclick` handler you can prevent the default anchor navigation by returning `false`:

```
<a href = "http://www.google.com" onclick="return whereAreYouGoing()">Go</a>

function whereAreYouGoing(){
    var exit = confirm("Are You Want to Sure to Leave?");
    if(exit){
       window.close();
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Although `window.close()` will attempt to close the current window - which in most browsers won't work unless the current window was opened via JavaScript in the first place. And if it does work it obviously won't then navigate to the specified URL.

It makes more sense to simply allow the default navigation (to google.com, in your example) if the user clicks OK:

```
function whereAreYouGoing(){
    return confirm("Are You Want to Sure to Leave?");
}
```

Comment: okay i did not see the return keyword, so it fixed, thanks a lot. :)